# String replacement with backslashes and inverted commas

Tags: python, replace

In Python I am trying to replace all instances of `"` in a string with `\"`, using the standard string `replace()` method.

So if I have as input `test string "hello"`, my expected output should be `test string \"hello\"`

However, I'm not getting expected results, with a variety of attempts.

I would think that having `\\` would print a single `\`, since we are escaping the escape character.  We can prove this by `print('\\')` which prints a `\`.

If I run the following code on a Python prompt, I get the expected result:

```
my_string = 'test string "hello"'
my_string = my_string.replace('"', f'\\"')
```

However, if I either save the string to a file, or print it in a Jupyter notebook, I do not get the expected output:

```
my_string = 'test string "hello"'

with open('test_file.txt', "w") as f:
    f.write(my_string.replace('"', f'\\"'))
```

This produces a text file with `test string \\"hello\\"`.

Comment: `my_string = my_string.replace('"', '\\"')`. Backslash is an escape character, so you need to escape it with a single`\\` before writing it.

Comment: If I print that to terminal, or to a file, I get `test string \\"hello\\"`, two backslashes.

Comment: I suspect that you are confusing the real content of the string with its representation. You should clarify what you want to achieve with some use case, what you want and what your real current problem is.

Comment: I get `test string \\"hello\\"` when printing on a Jupyter Notebook, or writing to a file with `f.write(wkl)`.  But yes, I get `test string \"hello\" ` when printing from a normal Python prompt

Comment: I suspect the problem could be with using `\\` with `f-string` which is not allowed and I get an error, could you just try with a plain string without `f-strings`?

Comment: have clarified the question.  I get unexpected behaviour when saving this string to a file, or printing it on a Jupyter notebook.  Printing to a prompt seems to be fine.  Removing `f-strings` does not change the behaviour.

Comment: You still haven't answered the essential question: what are you trying to do with these strings? You are talking sometimes about the printed string, sometimes about it's `repr()` that you can see in a terminal, or about the way the string appears in a file. So, you don't always see the same. You didn't clarify what you want to do with this string. Any answer we could give would be meaningless, as we still don't know if you are talking about the string itself or some of its representations in certain contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. In order to do this, you must use a properly formatted [escape character](https://www.w3schools.com/python/gloss_python_escape_characters.asp).

Perhaps this is what you're looking for?

**Code:**

```py
my_string = 'test string "hello"'

with open('test_file.txt', "w") as foo:
    foo.write(my_string.replace('"', '\\"'))
```

**Output:**

```py
# Written to new file test_file.txt

test string \"hello\"
```

Comment: thanks, I have updated the question.  I see my unexpected behaviour when saving the string to a file, or printing on a Jupyter notebook.  With a normal Python prompt print this gives the expected results

Comment: Updated my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
my_string = 'test string "hello"' 
my_string = my_string.replace('\"', ' \\" ')
print(my_string)
```

Comment: thanks, I have updated the question.  I see my unexpected behaviour when saving the string to a file, or printing on a Jupyter notebook.  With a normal Python prompt print this gives the expected results

Answer (score 0):

```
my_string = 'test string "hello"'
my_string.replace('"', '\\"')
```

This  thing works exactly fine, It's just the terminal which is showing you double slashes. Cause '\' is an escape sequence character.
You can verify it like this:

```
>>len(my_string)
19
>>len(my_string.replace('"', '\\"'))
21
```

For the updated part: You can use something like this:

```
with open('test_file.txt', "w") as f:
    f.write(my_string.replace('"', '\\"'))
```

But Be **aware** that **\"** means just **"** whenever you read it from the file..

Comment: thanks, I have updated the question.  I see my unexpected behaviour when saving the string to a file, or printing on a Jupyter notebook.  With a normal Python prompt print this gives the expected results

Comment: No problem always happy to help.